# How to provide the API File ActionResult with the size property?

Tags: c#, .net, file, download

I'm trying to create a download API with some properties of the file like last modified date, content type and size with:

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(...)
{            
    string contentType = ..;
    string fileName = ..;
    DateTimeOffset? lastModified = ...;
    long fileSize = ...; // File size in bytes
        
    return File(memory, contentType, fileName, lastModified, null);
}
```

This is the best overload I could found:

```
public virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string? fileDownloadName, DateTimeOffset? lastModified, EntityTagHeaderValue entityTag)
```

but it does not hold a parameter for size!
Is there a way to make the size to be passed to the client via my API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with adding it to the response headers:

```
Response.Headers.Add("File-Size", fileSize.ToString());
```